# zoom in/out (+/-) in webview android

Tags: android, android-webview

In my application I have one Webview and two buttons next and previous. First time load content from database after that I zoom my Webview and change the page using next button then display content but the zooming is stated.

So my question is that how I change a Webview in initial scale?

I used this:

```
web1.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

and after click on next page used this:

```
web1.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
web1.setInitialScale(100);
```

but no any effects.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `web1.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);` and `web1.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`